# How to stop this python function?

Tags: python

How can I stop this function? The `while` function runs even if the loop ends in an `if` or `else` statement.

I tried adding `break`, but it is still not working.

```py
def proallocate():
    q = True
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    pid = cur.execute("SELECT project_id FROM Upload WHERE status= ?", ("NULL",))
    while q:
        for pd in pid:
            a = str(pd)
            projectid = re.sub('[\(\),\{\}<>]', '', a)
            url = "localhost:8888/"+projectid+""
            print(url)
            req = requests.Session()
            resp = req.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
            project_status_latest = soup.find_all('tr')[-1].get_text()
            if ("Project Ready" in project_status_latest):
                proid[0] = projectid
                q = False
                break
            else:
                cur.execute("UPDATE Upload SET status = ? WHERE project_id = ?", ("Reserved", projectid))
                conn.commit()             
    return projectid
```

The expected result is, it should return a value from the `if` statement or it should return nothing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195884/discussion-on-question-by-jones-kumar-how-to-stop-this-python-function).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `while` loop. The `for` loop already iterates over all the project IDs, you don't need another loop. If the `for` loop doesn't find a matching project, the `while` loop will repeat infinitely.